# A hidden side menu and HTML5 colour conflict

Tags: javascript, html, color-picker

I have a side menu which is hidden and controlled via click on an icon:

```
  <a href="#" onclick="openMenuNav()" title="open menu" id="openmenu"><i class="fa fa-caret-square-left" style="font-size:18px"></i></span>
```

The openMenuNav() is as follows:

```
function openMenuNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4 )";
}
```

This functions fine except if I have a have an form with an input type of color it opens the standard color dialog box plus the side menu.

The code to call the color is

```
<input type="color" id="flat" name="colour" value="#000000" data-alias="" style="width:80px">
```

I would be grateful for solutions!

Comment: use `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Sorry I should have added that chosing a colour will not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `preventDefault` to prevent it's default action.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input type="color" id="flat" name="colour" value="#000000" data-alias="" style="width:80px">
```